# setResult() not working

Tags: android, debugging, onactivityresult

I'm making this school projet and I need to get back the result from the Activity I've called

```
startActivityForResult(Activity2, 100);
```

Then in the activity two I've this

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(....);
    final Intent BackToActivityOne = new Intent(Activity2.this, ActivityOne.class);
    if(requestCode = this.REQUESTCODEACTIVITY && resultCode = RESULT_OK && data != null){

        //from the activity2
        sum = data.getIntExtra("sum",0);

        //to the activity1
        BackToActivityOne.putExtra("total",sum);

        btn1.setOnClickListener(new view.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                BackToActivityOne.putExtra("code",1000);
                setResult(RESULT_OK,BackToActivityOne);
                finish();
            }
        });
        btn2.setOnClickListener(new view.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                BackToActivityOne.putExtra("code",1001);
                setResult(RESULT_OK,BackToActivityOne);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }//if
}//onActivityResult(...)
```

And here is the problem, when I click on btn1 or btn2 it kills my app.

But I want the app to go back to activity1 where I make the treatment

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
 super.onActivityResult(....);
 if(resultCode = RESULT_OK && data != null){
   final int Code = data.getIntExtra("code",0);

   if(code == 1000){
   //code to do
   }
   else if(code == 1001){
    //code to do
    }

  }//if
}//onActivityResult(...)
```

For sure I'm doing something wrong but I can't find what. Hopefully somebody can help me to find the error.

Comment: You are mixing things. onActivityResult is calback. Read http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing two things. `protected void onActivityResult` should be overriden only in activity one.

Activity two shold have two buttons as I figured out. yor code:

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(new view.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                final Intent BackToActivityOne = new Intent(Activity2.this, ActivityOne.class);
                BackToActivityOne.putExtra("code",1000);
                setResult(RESULT_OK,BackToActivityOne);
                finish();
            }
        });
```

should be in `onCreate` where you obtain your references from view. Not in `onActivityResult`. Remember to get view by id and initialize reference! I don't think that final is necessary for intent.

Answer (score 0):

Haaa yeah my bad i ve a third and a forth activity. 
1 activity start 2 then 2 start 3. 3 start 4 get back a result and start 4 again several times.
When this back  and forth is finished Activity 3 goes back to 2 then btn1 and btn2 text change and a new onclick method is set. This is why it s on an onactivityresult ().

For the final of my  intent that came from the auto correct of android studio. If i don't put final before. I Can t call it into my onclick method. Here is the error code.

```
     variable 'BacktoActivityOne' is accessed from whithin inner class, 
     needs to be declared final
```

what i need is:

- when activity 3 send back is result to activity 2 the text of the button change and as you can see on my first post, depending on witch button is clicked i putExtra() with different parameters. SO if btn1 is clicked "code" is 1001 if it's btn2 "code" is 1000.
- Now i want this to be sent to my main_activity here i named here activity1. then in the method onActivityResult() of the activity1 i get the code and do something if the code is 1000, and an other things if code is 1001.

But then when i click either btn1 or btn2. My app is killed, and nothing is send to activity1.

My guess is than there is something wrong with the Intent i've declared final on OnActivityresult (in activity2), because when i look at it on Activity3 or 4 android studio write it in "black" (color), but here on Activity2 my intent when i put it on the setResult(RESULT_OK, intent); <- here intent is colored in purple, not in black